# how to group or collapse the search results in azure cognitive search

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

Do we have any feature available on azure cognitive search for collapsing or grouping the results which is a most important and basic search feature available on most of the search engines.

example solr - https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.htmlhttps://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html

example - if i have a shirt in 4 different variant and search query returns all the 4 search result we can group them together and show only one result which can be taken as default.

Did anyone achieved this in azure cognitive search ?

Thanks,
Navneet

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is, when modeling the index mark the t-shirt size as Facetable.

In the following example, Business Title was marked as Facetable:

[image]

Comment: but how to collapse them ? i mean how would you return 1 t-shirt  instead of 4 , if they belongs to same group

Comment: I see ... I don't think there's such a feature. Let's wait and see if someone from MSFT can reply

Comment: I think the way I would solve this is add a complex field and add all the sizes to it.

Comment: But If I search for red tshirt that time I want a specific tshirt to return